# Not able to click/select element using JQuery in Laravel Dusk

Tags: jquery, laravel, laravel-dusk, laravel-dusk2

I am compiling a test case related to `bootstrap daterange-picker` in `Laravel Dusk`. In my test case I need to select two dates and click on apply button.

My code looks like:

```
$browser
    ->within('.drp-calendar .left', function ($browser) {
        $browser->within('.table-condensed', function ($browser) {
           $browser->within('tbody', function ($browser) {
             $browser->script("$('td[data-title=\\'r1c0\\']').click()");
            });
        });
    })
    ->within('.drp-calendar .right', function ($browser) {
        $browser->within('.table-condensed', function ($browser) {
           $browser->within('tbody', function ($browser) {
             $browser->script("$('td[data-title=\\'r3c4\\']').click()");
            });
        });
    })
    ->click('.drp-buttons > .applyBtn');
```

I am not getting any error but when apply button is clicked it is not selecting the desired dates. Or you can say the `JQuery` part is not click. Since I'm using external bootstrap package so I am unable to define dusk selectors, to achieve this I'm trying to click through data attributes.

**EDIT**

I took screenshot just above the jQuery statement and I can see my calendar is properly visible.

[image]

Any suggestions are welcomed. Thanks

Comment: I don't know the Bootstrap datepicker but are you sure it is already displayed? With standard jQueryUI datepicker I had to wait for it to open before I could target dates.  Or maybe the data atts aren't there yet? I'm sure you've already done it but double check your selectors, try copy-pasting them in devtools and make sure they work as expected.  Try taking a screenshot just before your `script()` clicks to make sure everything is as you expect.

Comment: @Don'tPanic Hi, I did check with the screenshots just before my `script()` and I can see my calendar is visible. I edited my question though with screenshot. Is my script code fine?

Comment: Your code looks fine to me, though you could try simplifying it maybe, without all the nested `within()`s? `$browser->script(".drp-calendar .left .table-condensed tbody td[data-title=\\'r1c0\\']").click();` ? Copy-paste the selector into devtools to make sure it works.

Comment: @Don'tPanic No luck. Same result.